# How use @ComponentScan in Spring Boot to load classes from jar and a wildcard that works like the default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

When I add `@ComponentScan` to my main class and pass the `basePackages' with the packages from my external jar, it no longer scans my project's packages. I can add those packages manually like:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.jar.classes","com.project.classes"})
```

But this means I'll have to manually keep that updated. Is there a way to say:

- Scan all packages like the default
- Add the jar's packages for scanning as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a simple configuration class which is in your project's packages that are picked up by the default component scan which includes a specific component scan for your external components.

i.e.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.jar.classes"})
public class ExternalComponentConfig {
}
```

Or it might actually be possible to include 2 component scans in your base config class like:

```
@ComponentScan
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.jar.classes"})
```

But i'm not 100% on that working whereas I am 100% on the first solution.